# LEFT join query not working in procedure Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, left-join

I have a query where it generates `18 digit code`.
Here is the logic for generating the 18 digit code.

1. R - Fix
2. AP – (GIS STATE refer B column from below table)
3. AP01- (SLP_STATE refer C column from below table)
4. SMT – (Format refer A Column from below table)
5. 4567 – Store Code

with above logic the code generated is like this `R-AN-SOUT--6715`

With above 18 digit code, there is 2 error.

1.) For point no second in above logic, where it takes `STATE` column it only takes the first two digit of the state.

For ex: If the state name is `Andhra Pradesh` it takes `AN` but actually it should take `AP`. Also, if the state name for `Mumbai` it should take `MU` where it is taking `MU` which is correct.

2.) For point number second it is not taking the `FORMAT` may be due to `left join` which brings data from another column.

Here is below the query and its description.

```
SELECT  'R' ||'-'|| UPPER(SUBSTR(r.STATE, 1, 2))  ||'-'|| UPPER(SUBSTR(r.ZONE_NAME, 1, 4)) 
||'-'|| s.FORMAT_CODE ||'-'||  SUBSTR(r.STORE_CODE, 1,4)
FROM tbl_rrsoc_store_info r
LEFT JOIN tbl_site_store_format s
ON r.STORE_CODE = s.FORMAT_CODE
 where r.STORE_CODE = '6715';
```

Also the table description

```
Table name:- TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO

Name                        Null     Type           
--------------------------- -------- -------------- 
RRSOC_ID                    NOT NULL NUMBER         
STORE_CODE                  NOT NULL NVARCHAR2(55)  
STATE                                NVARCHAR2(55)  
SLP_STATE                            NVARCHAR2(100) 
FORMAT_GROUP                         NVARCHAR2(100) 


Table name:- TBL_SITE_STORE_FORMAT
Name         Null Type          
------------ ---- ------------- 
ID                VARCHAR2(20)  
STORE_FORMAT      VARCHAR2(100) 
ISACTIVE          VARCHAR2(3)   
FORMAT_GROUP      VARCHAR2(100) 
FORMAT_CODE       VARCHAR2(50)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You are only selecting the first two characters of the state name. If you want the first letter of the second part of the name, you must code for it.
2. You are joining tbl_site_store_format on the wrong column, the value from each table should be store_code.

   ```
     SELECT    'R_'
         || CASE
                WHEN INSTR (TRIM (r.state), ' ') > 1
                THEN
                       SUBSTR (r.state, 1, 1)
                    || SUBSTR (r.state, INSTR (r.state, ' ') + 1, 1)
                ELSE
                    UPPER (SUBSTR (r.state, 1, 2))
            END
         || '-'
         || UPPER (SUBSTR (r.zone_name, 1, 4))
         || '-'
         || s.format_code
         || '-'
         || SUBSTR (r.store_code, 1, 4)
    FROM tbl_rrsoc_store_info  r
         LEFT JOIN tbl_site_store_format s ON r.store_code = s.store_code
   ```

Comment: hey brian, sorry for delayed response. But I am getting error as `ORA-00904: "S"."STORE_CODE": invalid identifier` but in `tbl_site_store_format` table there is no `store_code` column